# What happens to change tracking value when it reaches bigint limit?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

Let's say I have enabled change tracking on 200 tables in a database. Since the change tracking value change in the scope of database. What if I reach the max value of BIGINT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to reach `bigint` limit, you have to change 1 million rows in your database every second during the next 292471 years. Good luck reaching it.

Comment: I was just working out a similar "think about the numbers" value - you can make ~730 million changes per second if you "only" need the system to work for 400 years.